# Adding a timer to existing JS slider

Tags: javascript, timer, slider

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.
I'm building a online shop for a client and am using the PrestaShop Moon theme ([link](http://dgcraft.free.fr/blog/index.php/themes-prestashop/moon-theme-prestashop/)).  You'll notice in the demo that there is a slider.  However, the slider doesn't change automatically every few seconds like some sliders out there (for example this [one](http://ptb76.tk)).  The Moon theme uses an old slider created by [Brian Reindel](http://blog.reindel.com) which is no longer supported.

The themes slider also calls boot.js which only includes.

```
$(function() {

    $( "#slides" ).accessNews({
        speed : "normal",
        slideBy : 1
    });


});
```

So my question is taking the existing [.js](http://pastie.org/863352) can it be modified to auto-slide?

Thank you everyone for your help!

Comment: I've been at this for the last hour and still no luck, I tried ocdcoder's suggestion below, but due to my lack of experience with js, I can't get it to work.  http://pastie.org/863558 is the page that calls the js files and controls the sliders content.  Any help is appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just set an interval and invoke the "click" event on the arrow that scrolls. It should look something like the following:

```
function makeScroll() {
 $('#arrow').click();
}

setInterval(makeScroll, secs*1000);
```

where secs is the num of secs you want delayed

Comment: Pardon my noobieness, but where in the js file would I put this?

Comment: you could create a script tag at the bottom of the page the scroller is on

Comment: I tried that, as well as putting it in its own js file and calling it using
<script type="text/javascript" src="{$this_path}slider/autoscroll.js"></script> In the same file that slider.js and boot.js are called.  Didnt work.  I must be missing something simple.

Comment: maybe #arrow isn't correct, I tried #next and someothers but no luck

Comment: yea, sorry, '#arrow' is just a placeholder. lemme look at the template and find the actual selector for ya

Comment: try: $('#slides > .next > a')