# I have a slider with buttons to go to pre or next, but i also want to put interval in it

Tags: jquery, html, header, slider, intervals

I have a slider header with 8 images. With the buttons > < i can flip through the images. But I also would like to put some kind of interval or timer on the header so it will change every ten seconds or so. This is my html

```
    <section id="gallery-2-49251">
    <div class="carousel">
        <div class="viewport">
            <div class="items">
                <article>
                    <div class="media-4" data-size="1920x0">
                        <img src="./assets/images/industrial1.1920x0.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col col-md-6">                          
                                <div class="middle">
                                    <div>
                                        <div class="heading-1">Industrial</div>
                                        <div class="text-2"><p>Remote Sensing Solutions</p></div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <article>
                    <div class="media-4" data-size="1920x0">
                        <img src="./assets/images/infrastructure1.1920x0.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col col-md-6">
                                <div class="middle">
                                    <div>
                                        <div class="heading-1">Infrastructure</div>
                                        <div class="text-2"><p>Remote Sensing Solutions
</p></div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <article>
                    <div class="media-4" data-size="1920x0">
                        <img src="./assets/images/construction1.1920x0.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col col-md-6">
                                <div class="middle">
                                    <div>
                                        <div class="heading-1">Construction</div>
                                        <div class="text-2"><p>Remote Sensing Solutions
</p></div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <article>
                    <div class="media-4" data-size="1920x0">
                        <img src="./assets/images/water-management1.1920x0.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col col-md-6">
                                <div class="middle">
                                    <div>
                                        <div class="heading-1">Watermanagement</div>
                                        <div class="text-2"><p>Remote Sensing Solutions
</p></div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <article>
                    <div class="media-4" data-size="1920x0">
                        <img src="./assets/images/industrial2.1920x0.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col col-md-6">
                                <div class="middle">
                                    <div>
                                        <div class="heading-1">Industrial</div>
                                        <div class="text-2"><p>Remote Sensing Solutions
</p></div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <article>
                    <div class="media-4" data-size="1920x0">
                        <img src="./assets/images/infrastructure2.1920x0.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col col-md-6">
                                <div class="middle">
                                    <div>
                                        <div class="heading-1">Infrastructure</div>
                                        <div class="text-2"><p>Remote Sensing Solutions
</p></div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <article>
                    <div class="media-4" data-size="1920x0">
                        <img src="./assets/images/construction2.1920x0.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col col-md-6">
                                <div class="middle">
                                    <div>
                                        <div class="heading-1">Construction</div>
                                        <div class="text-2"><p>Remote Sensing Solutions
</p></div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <article>
                    <div class="media-4" data-size="1920x0">
                        <img src="./assets/images/water-management2.1920x0.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col col-md-6">
                                <div class="middle">
                                    <div>
                                        <div class="heading-1">Watermanagement</div>
                                        <div class="text-2"><p>Remote Sensing Solutions
</p></div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="prev hidden-xs visible-sm">&lt;</a>
        <a href="#" class="next hidden-xs visible-sm">&gt;</a>
        <div class="bullets"></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

And this is my .js

```
var Carousel = function(options){this.init(options);};

Carousel.prototype =
{
    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param   object options
     * @return  void
     */
    init: function(options)
    {
        this.options =
        {
            selector    : '.carousel',
            interval    : 500,
            play        : false,
            slide       : false,
            index       : 0
        };

        $.extend(this.options, options);

        this.window         = $(window);
        this.carousel_node  = $();
        this.items_node     = $();
        this.item_nodes     = $();
        this.image_nodes    = $();
        this.video_nodes    = $();
        this.play_node      = $();
        this.timeline_node  = $();
        this.bullet_nodes   = $();
        this.tab_nodes      = $();

        this.item_index = this.options.index;
        this.item_count = 0;
        this.transition = (typeof document.body.style.transition !== 'undefined');

        this.start();
    },

    /**
     * Start
     * @return void
     */
    start: function()
    {
        var _this       = this;
        var selectors   = this.options.selector.split(',');

        if (selectors.length > 1)
        {
            for (var x in selectors)
            {
                var options = $.extend({}, this.options);

                options.selector = $.trim(selectors[x]);

                new Carousel(options);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var carousel_nodes = $(this.options.selector);

            carousel_nodes.each(function(index)
            {
                if (index)
                {
                    var options = $.extend({}, _this.options);

                    options.selector += ':eq('+index+')';

                    new Carousel(options);
                }
                else
                {
                    _this.carousel_node = $(this);
                    _this.items_node    = _this.carousel_node.find('.items:first');
                    _this.item_nodes    = _this.items_node.children('article');
                    _this.play_node     = _this.carousel_node.find('.play:first');
                    _this.timeline_node = _this.carousel_node.find('.timeline:first');
                    _this.tab_nodes     = _this.carousel_node.find('.tab');
                    _this.item_count    = _this.item_nodes.length;

                    var item_node       = _this.item_nodes.eq(_this.item_index);
                    var bullets_node    = _this.carousel_node.find('.bullets:first');
                    var tab_node        = _this.tab_nodes.eq(_this.item_index);
                    var tab_width       = 100 / _this.item_count;

                    _this.tab_nodes.css('width', tab_width+'%');

                    for (var i=0; i<_this.item_count; i++)
                    {
                        var bullet_node = $('<a>', {href: '#', 'class': 'bullet'});

                        if (i == _this.item_index) bullet_node.addClass('active');

                        bullets_node.append(bullet_node);
                    }

                    _this.bullet_nodes = bullets_node.find('.bullet');

                    if (_this.options.slide)
                    {
                        var item_clones_1   = _this.item_nodes.clone();
                        var item_clones_2   = _this.item_nodes.clone();
                        var items_left      = -100 * _this.item_count;
                        var items_width     = 100 * (_this.item_count * 3);
                        var item_width      = 100 / (_this.item_count * 3);

                        _this.carousel_node.addClass('slide');

                        item_clones_1.add(item_clones_2).addClass('clone');
                        _this.items_node.prepend(item_clones_1).append(item_clones_2);

                        _this.image_nodes   = _this.items_node.find('article img');
                        _this.video_nodes   = _this.items_node.find('article video, article iframe');

                        _this.items_node.addClass('notransition').css({left: items_left+'%', width: items_width+'%'}).height();
                        _this.items_node.removeClass('notransition');

                        var item_nodes = _this.items_node.children('article');

                        item_nodes.css('width', item_width+'%');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _this.image_nodes   = _this.items_node.find('article img');
                        _this.video_nodes   = _this.items_node.find('article video, article iframe');
                    }

                    item_node.addClass('active');
                    tab_node.addClass('active');

                    _this.scaleImages();
                    _this.setVideos();
                    _this.setEvents();

                    if (_this.options.play || _this.play_node.length)
                    {
                        _this.play_node.toggleClass('play stop');

                        _this.setTimer();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    },

    /**
     * Scale images
     * @param   object image_node
     * @return  void
     */
    scaleImages: function(image_node)
    {
        var _this = this;

        if (image_node)
        {
            var image_height    = image_node.height();
            var item_node       = image_node.parents('article:first');
            var item_height     = item_node.outerHeight();

            if (image_height < item_height) image_node.css({height: '101%', width: 'auto'});
        }
        else
        {
            this.image_nodes.css({height: '', width: ''});

            this.image_nodes.each(function()
            {
                var image_node      = $(this);
                var image_height    = image_node.height();

                if (image_height)
                {
                    var item_node   = image_node.parents('article:first');
                    var item_height = item_node.outerHeight();

                    if (image_height < item_height) image_node.css({height: '101%', width: 'auto'});
                }
                else
                {
                    image_node.load(function()
                    {
                        _this.scaleImages(image_node);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    },

    /**
     * Set videos
     * @return void
     */
    setVideos: function()
    {
        var _this = this;

        this.video_nodes.each(function()
        {
            var video_node  = $(this);
            var image_node  = video_node.next('img');

            if (image_node.length)
            {
                var is_video    = video_node.is('video');
                var play_node   = $('<a>', {href: '#', 'class': 'play'});

                image_node.after(play_node);

                play_node.click(function(event)
                {
                    event.preventDefault();

                    image_node.add(play_node).hide();

                    if (is_video) video_node.get(0).play();
                });
            }
        });
    },

    /**
     * Set events
     * @return void
     */
    setEvents: function()
    {
        var _this       = this;
        var item_node   = this.item_nodes.first();
        var prev_node   = this.carousel_node.find('.prev:first');
        var next_node   = this.carousel_node.find('.next:first');

        this.window.resize(function()
        {
            _this.scaleImages();
        });

        /*****************/
        /* transitionend */
        /*****************/
        if (this.transition)
        {
            this.items_node.bind('transitionend', function(event)
            {
                event.stopPropagation();

                if (_this.item_index < 0 || _this.item_index >= _this.item_count)
                {
                    var item_index  = _this.translateIndex(_this.item_index);
                    var items_left  = -(100 * _this.item_count) - (100 * item_index);

                    _this.items_node.addClass('notransition').css('left', items_left+'%').height();
                    _this.items_node.removeClass('notransition');

                    _this.item_index = item_index;
                }
            });

            this.item_nodes.bind('transitionend', function(event)
            {
                event.stopPropagation();

                var item_node = $(this);

                item_node.removeClass('passive');
            });
        }

        /*********/
        /* touch */
        /*********/
        var touch_x_start       = 0;
        var touch_y_start       = 0;
        var touch_x_end         = 0;
        var touch_y_end         = 0;
        var prev_touch_x        = 0;
        var prev_touch_y        = 0;
        var touch_time_start    = 0;
        var touch_valid         = true;

        this.items_node.bind(
        {
            touchstart: function(event)
            {
                prev_touch_x    = event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
                prev_touch_y    = event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;
                touch_valid     = _this.validateIndex(_this.item_index, 1);

                if (touch_valid)
                {
                    touch_x_start       = prev_touch_x;
                    touch_y_start       = prev_touch_y;
                    touch_x_end         = prev_touch_x;
                    touch_y_end         = prev_touch_y;
                    touch_time_start    = event.timeStamp;

                    _this.items_node.addClass('notransition');
                }
            },
            touchmove: function(event)
            {
                var touch_x         = event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
                var touch_y         = event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;
                var touch_x_move    = touch_x - prev_touch_x;
                var touch_y_move    = touch_y - prev_touch_y;

                if (Math.abs(touch_x_move) > Math.abs(touch_y_move))
                {
                    event.preventDefault();

                    if (touch_valid && _this.options.slide)
                    {
                        var items_position  = _this.items_node.position();
                        var items_left      = items_position.left;

                        items_left += touch_x_move;

                        _this.items_node.css('left', items_left);
                    }
                }

                prev_touch_x    = touch_x;
                prev_touch_y    = touch_y;
                touch_x_end     = touch_x;
                touch_y_end     = touch_y;
            },
            touchend: function(event)
            {
                if (touch_valid)
                {
                    _this.items_node.height();
                    _this.items_node.removeClass('notransition');

                    var touch_x_moved   = touch_x_end - touch_x_start;
                    var touch_y_moved   = touch_y_end - touch_y_start;

                    if (touch_x_moved)
                    {
                        var item_index = _this.item_index;

                        if (Math.abs(touch_x_moved) > Math.abs(touch_y_moved * 2))
                        {
                            var touch_time_end  = event.timeStamp;
                            var touch_time      = touch_time_end - touch_time_start;
                            var swipe           = (Math.abs(touch_x_moved) >= 50 && touch_time <= 250);

                            if (_this.options.slide)
                            {
                                var item_width  = item_node.width();
                                var items_moved = touch_x_moved / item_width;

                                item_index -= swipe ? (touch_x_moved > 0 ? Math.ceil(items_moved) : Math.floor(items_moved)) : Math.round(items_moved);
                            }
                            else if (swipe)
                            {
                                item_index += touch_x_moved > 0 ? -1 : 1;
                            }

                            _this.showItem(item_index);
                        }
                        else if (_this.options.slide)
                        {
                            _this.showItem(item_index);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        /*************/
        /* prev/next */
        /*************/
        prev_node.add(next_node).click(function(event)
        {
            event.preventDefault();

            var prev_node   = $(this);
            var is_prev     = prev_node.hasClass('prev');
            var item_index  = _this.item_index + (is_prev ? -1 : 1);

            _this.showItem(item_index);
        });

        /********/
        /* play */
        /********/
        this.play_node.click(function(event)
        {
            event.preventDefault();

            var is_stop = _this.play_node.hasClass('stop');

            _this.options.play = (is_stop == false);

            _this.play_node.toggleClass('play stop');

            _this.setTimer(is_stop);
        });

        /****************/
        /* bullets/tabs */
        /****************/
        this.bullet_nodes.add(this.tab_nodes).click(function(event)
        {
            event.preventDefault();

            var bullet_node     = $(this);
            var is_bullet       = bullet_node.hasClass('bullet');
            var bullet_index    = is_bullet ? _this.bullet_nodes.index(bullet_node) : _this.tab_nodes.index(bullet_node);

            _this.showItem(bullet_index);
        });
    },

    /**
     * Show item
     * @param   integer index
     * @return  void
     */
    showItem: function(index)
    {
        if (this.validateIndex(index))
        {
            var alt_index = this.translateIndex(index);

            if (alt_index != this.item_index)
            {
                var item_node           = this.item_nodes.eq(alt_index);
                var active_item_node    = this.item_nodes.filter('.active:first');
                var bullet_node         = this.bullet_nodes.eq(alt_index);
                var active_bullet_node  = this.bullet_nodes.filter('.active:first');
                var tab_node            = this.tab_nodes.eq(alt_index);
                var active_tab_node     = this.tab_nodes.filter('.active:first');
                var active_video_node   = active_item_node.find('video:first');

                item_node.addClass('active');
                active_item_node.removeClass('active');

                bullet_node.addClass('active');
                active_bullet_node.removeClass('active');

                tab_node.addClass('active');
                active_tab_node.removeClass('active');

                if (active_video_node.length) active_video_node.get(0).pause();

                if (!this.options.slide)
                {
                    if (this.transition) active_item_node.addClass('passive');

                    this.item_index = alt_index;
                }

                if (this.options.play) this.setTimer();
            }

            if (this.options.slide)
            {
                var items_left = -(100 * this.item_count) - (100 * index);

                this.items_node.css('left', items_left+'%');

                this.item_index = index;
            }
        }
    },

    /**
     * Set timer
     * @param   boolean stop
     * @return  void
     */
    setTimer: function(stop)
    {
        var _this = this;

        this.timeline_node.stop().css('padding-right', '100%');

        if (!stop)
        {
            this.timeline_node.animate({'padding-right': 0}, this.options.interval, 'linear', function()
            {
                var item_index = _this.item_index + 1;

                _this.showItem(item_index);
                _this.setTimer();
            });
        }
    },

    /**
     * Translate index
     * @param   integer index
     * @return  integer
     */
    translateIndex: function(index)
    {
        if (!$.isNumeric(index)) index = 0;

        if (index < 0 || index >= this.item_count)
        {
            index = index < 0 ? this.item_count + index : index - this.item_count
        }

        return index;
    },

    /**
     * Validate index
     * @param   integer index
     * @param   integer margin
     * @return  boolean
     */
    validateIndex: function(index, margin)
    {
        if (!margin) margin = 0;

        return ($.isNumeric(index) && index >= -(this.item_count - margin) && index < ((this.item_count * 2) - margin));
    }
};
```

I have a slider header with 8 images. With the buttons > < i can flip through the images. But I also would like to put some kind of interval or timer on the header so it will change every ten seconds or so. How do i put interval in my slider? I would like to add an interval of 10 sec or so.

Answer (score 0):

Something I have found on another topic is to do the following
[Adding a timer to existing JS slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418453/adding-a-timer-to-existing-js-slider)

The idea is to  create an interval as below

```
function makeScroll() {
 $('#arrow').click();
}

setInterval(makeScroll, secs*1000);
```